# Could not find class org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMSchemeFactory

Tags: android, apache, httpclient, ntlm

I have httpclient-4.3.1.jar added in my java build path. I see org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMSchemeFactory in the jar. My app build without error, however, when I run it it shows "Could not find class 'org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMSchemeFactory" in logcat. Any suggestion?

Comment: why do you add httpclient as an external jar when it is included in android (and when httpurlconnection is recommended, too)?

Comment: solved it, had to check httpclient-4.3.1.jar in order and export tab in java build  path